# Module '"url"' has no exported member 'fileURLToPath'.ts(2305)

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

Importing `fileURLToPath` in `.ts` file results to: `Module "url" has no exported member 'fileURLToPath'.ts(2305)` error. Import:

```
...
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
...
```

Node types are installed via:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
     ...
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
     ...
  }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",  
    "module": "es2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    ...
```

Node version: `18.15.0`

Typescript version: `5.0.3`

Question: What I am doing incorrectly and how to get rid of the error?

Comment: According to the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#urlfileurltopathurl), your import should look like this : `import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';`

Comment: @YassinHajaj this leads to "Cannot find module 'node:url' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)"

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: @Evert edited my question with version information

Comment: Did you try `nodenext` for module resolution?

Comment: @morganney changing the module resolution to "NodeNext" did not resolve the issue